# Add String array into Calendar Array

Tags: java, arrays, calendar, simpledateformat

Basically I need to take a dynamic string array(which will be populated from a database but in this example its just a fixed size for testing purposes) from a database, convert it into a Calendar array so that I can compare it to the current day iteration to see if it equals a saturday/sunday or any days in the newly created Calendar Array.

My Question is the Calendar array isnt being populated right as it isnt being taken into account when the while loop compares current day against the holidays set?

This is my code so far;

```
private static final String[] bankHolidays = {"25/03/2016","28/03/16","02/05/2016","20/05/2016"};
private static Set<Calendar> holidayDates;
static SimpleDateFormat  sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {


    if(holidayDates == null) {
        holidayDates = new HashSet<Calendar>();
        Date[] hol = new Date[bankHolidays.length];
        for(int i=0;i<bankHolidays.length;i++){
            Date d = sdf.parse(bankHolidays[i]);
            hol[i]= d;

        }

        for(Date day : hol) {
          Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
          c.setTime(day);
          holidayDates.add(c);
        }
      }
```

In the comparing stage the code is;

```
if (startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SATURDAY && startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK) != Calendar.SUNDAY && !holidayDates.contains(startCal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR)) ) {

            ++workDays;

        }
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT: I figured out to do it in the end but one of the contributing factors was using MM instead of mm to compare the dates together.

Comment: Im not sure quite what your question is but your date format is incorrect. You probably want `"dd/MM/yyyy"`

Comment: @ug_ When I run the code even though 2 of the dates are in May, it still formats all the dates as January. The question is how do I go from a string array to creating a calendar array that I can compare the current day in the while loop to see if it matchs a saturday,sunday or a holiday?

Comment: @Rob format then should be `dd/MM/yyyy`, because `mm` means "minutes", not "month", that's why you always get january. This is a very common mistake.

Comment: @Sasha Yeah I've changed that now thanks. Its still not picking up that there are 2 bank holidays in May?

Comment: @Rob make sure that you erase time information when converting `Date` to `Calendar` for dates obtained from DB, and make it in proper timezone. To make `Calendar` instances be equal (in order to make `Set#contains()` work properly) they must also have the same time part, not only date part.

Comment: If you use Java 8, consider switching from `Set<Calendar>` to `Set<LocalDate>`, making processing dates without time easier and cleaner.

Comment: @Sasha I ended up in the IF statement looping through the holidays set to see if the current day equals any holiday in there, If it did then it set a boolean to true.
At the end of the code where it added 1 to workingdays if the boolean was true then it would skip it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fixed, cleaner version of your code sample :) (with your JDK5 language level. May be further improved by java 8 streams API)

```
private static final String[] bankHolidays = {"25/03/2016", "28/03/16", "02/05/2016", "20/05/2016"};
private static final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
private static Set<Calendar> holidayDates;

public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    if (holidayDates == null) {
        holidayDates = new HashSet<Calendar>();
        for (int i = 0; i < bankHolidays.length; i++) {
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            Date date = sdf.parse(bankHolidays[i]);
            c.setTime(date);
            holidayDates.add(c);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In Java 8, it could be significantly improved by using `LocalDate` instead of `Calendar`

Comment: yeah, new Date API can also help. But somehow he wants Calendar instances =)

Comment: "somehow" almost always mean "didn't know about alternative solution" :) `LocalDate` is much better because by using it you get rid of bugs resulting by wrong time erasure, wrong timezone etc.